# Restrict part of the lambda expression by type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I want to do something like this:

```
public string DoSomething(Expression<Func<int>> expression)
{
    //...
}

public void CallDoSomething()
{
    var myObj = new MyType();
    var result = DoSomething(() => myObj.IntProperty);
}
```

The goal is to do these three things within "DoSomething()":
1) Get a reference to myObj and do something with it
2) Get the name and value of the property "IntProperty"
3) Restrict myObj to be only of type MyType

I can do 1 and 2, but I cannot figure out how to do 3!

Please help.

Cheers

Comment: I haven't found a solution, but for now I'm just adding a line of code to DoSomething which basically says if (myObj.GetType() != typeof(MyType))...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OfType<T>()` method?

Comment: Not without an IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string DoSomething(Expression<Func<int>> expression) 
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    Type type = memberExpression.Member.ReflectedType; // MyType

    bool check = typeof(MyType).IsAssignableFrom(type); // So you could check for base class
    // If you want to check for exactly one class, do 
    // bool type == typeof(MyType);

    if (!check) 
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: It's sort of what I am already using as a solution, but I think you handled the check better than I did (I used .GetType() ==). What I wanted was a method that allows compile time check safetely.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is ... odd, and I don't know why the GetType solution isn't acceptable, but you could probably achieve something similar with another layer:

```
public string DoSomething(Expression<Func<int>> expression)
{
    //...
}

public void CallDoSomething()
{
    var myObj = new MyType();
    var result = CallHelper(myObj);
}

private string CallHelper(MyType m)
{
    return DoSomething(() => m.IntProperty);
}
```

CallHelper enforces the type restriction for you. I don't think there's any way to do it directly in the lambda expression (at least not without changing the signature of DoSomething), but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Changing the signature of DoSomething is completely okay. But I'm just not sure how to solve this particular problem just by changing the signature.

Comment: Maybe DoSomething(T obj, Expression<Func<int>> exp) where T : MyType {}. The call would look like DoSomething(myObj, () => myObj.IntProperty); The down side is that there is no gaurentee that the lambda expression is based on MyType or is even the same object as the first parameter.